# Is java 7 automatically use multiple cores in some cases?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-7

I build a simple but CPU intense java application.

I noticed that all 4 cores are at 100%.

Is java doing automatically multi-threading if the compiler sees that it is possible?

In this case I use loops and recursion. So may be the compiler realizes that multi-threading is possible?

The algorithm is part of calculating a Viterbi path

```
private Node buildTreeStructure(ArrayList<String[]> sentence, int i, Node parentNode, Node bestLeaf) {
        if (i == sentence.size()) {
            if (bestLeaf == null || bestLeaf.data.percentage < parentNode.data.percentage)
                bestLeaf = parentNode;
            return bestLeaf;
        }

        String[] word = sentence.get(i);
        for (String pos: allStates.keySet()) {
            double prob = calculateTransitionAndWordProbability(pos, word[WORD], getParent(parentNode.data.pos));
            if (prob > 0.000001) {
                logger.debug("Probability for " + word[WORD] + "/" + pos);
                NodeData nd = new NodeData(pos, word[WORD], prob * parentNode.data.percentage);
                Node n = new Node(nd, parentNode, new ArrayList<Node>());
                parentNode.children.add(n);
                bestLeaf = buildTreeStructure(sentence, i+1, n, bestLeaf);
            }
        }

        return bestLeaf;
    }
```

Comment: No, Java doesn't automatically parallelize your code.

Comment: But why 100% of four cores is utilized... What tool you use to measure CPU? Can it show 400% for four cores like `top`?

Comment: I use the Windows Task Manager. It show about 100% for each core. As soon as the java applications starts running. And I didn't do mulit-threading

Comment: Look at it with JVisualVM (JDK_PATH/bin/jvisualvm.exe). The 100% in the graphs are maybe caused by latency: the JVM jumps so fast from core to core that it looks like all cores are used 100% although they are only at 100% for 1/4 of time.

Comment: May be you use some libraries, that use multithreading? Try to reduce your code step wise to a simple loop, noticing CPU behavior. `while (true) {}` will definitely utilize only one CPU at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its your Operating System which is forced to utilize all the cores at once at that time. You can't specify the processor affinity in Java. So, this is actually left up to the OS, not the JVM. It's all about how your OS handles threads.

You could split your Java threads into separate processes and wrap them up in native code, to put one process per core.